# Elementary Lie theory : proving that the Lie bracket is a vector field? (well defined)

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-algebras

Most proofs i checked are written with a local coordinate patch, is there a simple coordinate independent formulation on how to verify that [X, Y] (f) is indeed a vector field? My teacher didn't bother to write it down.

Also i understand how we get to the double sum expression of the bracket (thanks to the leibniz rule among other things) but why do the second derivatives cancel out at the end?  Thanks.

Comment: Look [Lee's smooth manifold Ch.8](https://books.google.co.id/books/about/Introduction_to_Smooth_Manifolds.html?id=eqfgZtjQceYC&redir_esc=y)

Comment: Thank you @Sou燈馬想  that's a pretty concise and concrete book there. 

DietrichBurde yes that thread answers part of the question.